# download laravel 5.1 instead of laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php

when i downloaded the laravel package using

> laravel new porjectName

the composer downloaded the last version of laravel **5.2**

the question is how to make the composer download the **laravel 5.1** instead of the latest version **5.2** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use composer

> composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.1.*

Answer (score -2):

as mentioned in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) you can use

> composer create-project laravel/laravel your-directory "5.1.*"